# How to test/debug tree shaking in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter comes with tree shaking compilation. Including only the code used.

But this is easily breakable inadvertently.

Is there any way to test and debug tree shaking?

Comment: How is it easily breakable?

Comment: Things such as `if platform === IOS then CupertinoButton else MaterialButton` actually breaks tree shaking. As the compiler assumes this variable can change over time

Comment: Did you try comparing binary sizes?

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33920

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For debugging, it is possible to connect to the Observatory in profile mode. Then inspect the content of desired dart file

You won't see the actual sources in profile mode; but you'll see an overview of what is inside the file, including the defined classes and their methods.

For example, a widget such a the following:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  _unused() {
    print('home');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

when inspected in the Observatory in profile mode; `_unused` method will not be in the function list:

[image]

Comment: hi have you found a way to check whether tree shaking is enabled for each line in a function ?

Comment: If you are writing a platform specific widget (Material vs Cupertino), using conditional to render for each platform, when building apps for android or ios does it tree shake the unused platform widget??

Comment: No. This will ship both platforms

Comment: Can the same be done for a dart application rather than a flutter app ?

Comment: Could not find this place. Is thing still available? Where can I see contents of a class?

Answer (score 0):

There is now an [App Size DevTool](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/app-size) that comes already with Flutter.

First, generate json with your app's size report (eg for linux):

```
flutter build linux --analyze-size --release
```

Next, run the tool with the generated report (change your path):

```
flutter pub global run devtools --appSizeBase=/home/tomek/.flutter-devtools/linux-code-size-analysis_01.json
```

In the [Analysis tab](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/app-size#analysis-tab) just check out go to `Library or Class` section and navigate to your code: `Root->bundle->lib->libapp.so (Dart AOT)-><your package name>`