# Will the dart codes for iOS be removed when compiling for Android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, compilation

I'm using flutter to write an app for both iOS and Android platforms. Some functions are not the same.

For example:

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
    int onlyForiOS = 10;
    onlyForiOS++;
    print("$onlyForiOS");
}
else if (Platform.isAndroid){
    int onlyForAndroid = 20;
    onlyForAndroid++;
    print("$onlyForAndroid");
}
```

When I build for the Android platform, will the codes for iOS be compiled into the binary file? Or they are just removed for optimization?
For security reason, I don't want any of the codes for iOS appeared in the Android binary file.

Comment: I don't claim myself to be an expert on this, but I think your complied Android code will also contain if part (for iOS)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad So is that an assumption? I'm really expecting a solid answer because I have to take alternative plans to code if what you said is true.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33920 and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822353/how-to-test-debug-tree-shaking-in-flutter

Comment: @RockingDice it is my assumption, Remi mentions that too.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks for the links. They are really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on what expression you are evaluating.

Dart tree-shaking is based on constant variables. As such, the following will be tree-shaked:

```
const foo = false;
if (foo) {
  // will be removed on release builds
}
```

But this example won't:

```
final foo = false;
if (foo) {
  // foo is not a const, therefore this if is not tree-shaked
}
```

---

Now if we look at the implementation of `Platform.isAndroid`, we can see that it is **not** a constant, but instead a getter.

Therefore we can deduce that `if (Platform.isAndroid)` won't be tree-shaked.

Comment: I think it's clear to answer this question for my case, I'll find another way. But it really depends on the codes whether to do tree-shaking for other situations. It would be better if you can share more information about 'Dart tree-shaking is based on constant variables' part :)