# How to test whether tree-shaking is applied to unused funciton in dart

Tags: dart, tree-shaking

Consider following dart code:

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'module.dart';

main() {
  foo();
}
```

`module.dart`

```dart
foo() {
  print('foo');
}

bar() {
  print('bar');
}
```

I expect `bar` to be eliminated from the final build by dart compiler with tree-shaking since it's statically analyzable that the function was not used in `main`.

I tried the method answered in [related S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822353/how-to-test-debug-tree-shaking-in-flutter).
Using devtools by running `dart run --observe main.dart`, I still see `bar` was included.

[image: devtools]

How can I know whether `bar` was eliminated from the final build or not?

Alternatively, I want someone with an understanding of dart compiler to convince me whether the function was eliminated or not, so I don't need to worry about checking it myself.

Comment: A quick way may be `dart compile js -o main.js main.dart ; egrep '(foo|bar)' main.js` that gives `H.printString("foo");` but no output for `bar`. Of course it's a bit more complicated if you don't have anything obvious to grep for.